# 92% hang up when running ng serve on project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I am attempting to run ng serve but my project keeps hanging up at 92% and not running.

```
    92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\assets\js\demo\chart-area-demo.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:129:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:42:54)
    at Promise (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:69:49)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at scripts.map.fullPath (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:68:24)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at hook (C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:67:43)
```

Comment: Probably file is not available at this ('C:\Users\Blayne Bennett\Desktop\the-nibblonians\client\assets\js\demo\chart-area-demo.js') location. Please confirm!

Comment: Yeah so there was previously that file there but i removed it. Do i need to change something somewhere else because of that? Thanks ahead of time

Comment: No just change the file path to the newer one wherever you are using it and that is all!

Comment: Hey sorry for the delayed response. So i deleted that file from the entire project and im pretty sure its not referenced anywhere else but its still giving me the issue

Comment: ctrl+f+shift (in most IDEs) to the rescue (project-wide search by string). Then start you command again

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ng serve` in windows power shell, if you are using windows system.

After using powershell, compilation time got improved than earlier. Give it a try.